# Unable to load type NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate

As I read and try every topic similar without success, I decided to post my own question. My solution has a console app and a class library for dataaccess. The Nhibernate configuration is inside the appconfig in the console app (which I'm currently using for debug, as I will after make a Web App and migrate all configuration to web.config).

The exception is well know:

NHibernate.Bytecode.UnableToLoadProxyFactoryFactoryException: Unable to load type NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll' during configuration of proxy factory class. Possible causes are: - The NHibernate.Bytecode provider assembly was not deployed. - The typeName used to initialize the 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory section is not well formed. Solution: Confirm that your deployment folder contains one of the following assemblies: NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The steps I took to try to solve it:

1) The dll in the deployment folder - I have the following dll in my bin:

> Castle.Core.dll - v. 2.5.1
>   Iesi.Collections.dll - v.2.0.0.1002
>   log4net.dll - v. 1.2.10.0
>   NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll - v.3.0.0.2001 
>   NHibernate.dll - v.3.1.0.4000

2) The configuration contains

name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,NHibernate.ByteCode

3) I set my MetaManager.Data project to deploy in a x86 CPU
4) All dll in my bin folder are referenced in the project.

I think this it it. I do not know were else to go :(

Answer (score 1):

To find out which dlls are loaded or rejected by which component you can use the "Assembly Binding Log Viewer" (Fuslogvw.exe) that belongs to the dotnetsdk . If logging is enabled it can show you wich assemblies are loaded and which assembly caused it to load.

For details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think the version of the Iesi.Collections and NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle assemblies should be the same as for the NHibnernate assembly, i.e. 3.1.0.4000 (at least that's the version of the assemblies distributed with NH 3.1.0 GA).

Comment: I changed  NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle to the  3.0.0.4000 . It's not helped

Comment: Looks like you are using NH 3.1 so I've updated my answer accordingly.